# Steps to open a php project sent to me

Tags: php

after open the project and create database,,,,

Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'id18629747_netmonitor_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the user and grant it privileges to access your database. Via mysql console for example:

```
create user id18629747_netmonitor_user@localhost identified by '%YOUR_PASSWORD_HERE%';
grant all on %YOUR_DATABASE_NAME_HERE% to id18629747_netmonitor_user@localhost;
```